# How to compare 1st element and operate 2nd element in 2D list in python

Tags: python

I have a 2D list (list of lists) in python in this format:

```
x=[[1,'A'],[1,'B'],[2,'A'],[3,'T'],[3,'Z'],[8,'K'],[6,'K'],[8,'N']]
```

I want to compare the first element that is integer and if the number is equal to another number in the list then combine their 2nd element i.e. alphabet.
Desired Output (List of strings):

```
["1:'A','B'","2:'A'","3:'T','Z'","8:'K',N'","6:'K'"]
```

I did try to use for loop but it is not checking the similarity of more than 2 elements. Is there any other simpler method for this?

My attempt:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i][0]==x[i+1][0]:
        print x[i][-1]+","+x[i+1][-1]
    else:
        print x[i][-1]
```

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Yes but it is not giving output anywhere close to the desired result. So I did not post it. But I used 2 for loops but the logic looks incorrect.

Comment: Please add your attempt to the question

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Added

Comment: is it python2.7?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Yes

Comment: the output looks pretty close to a dictionary, do you need a dictionary instead of list of strings

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh No sir, I need a list of string.We can use any seperator instead of ":". That was just to denote that is it separating.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
x=[[1,'A'],[1,'B'],[2,'A'],[3,'T'],[3,'Z'],[8,'K'],[6,'K'],[8,'N']]
result = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in x:
    result[k].append(v)

result = ["{}: {}".format(k, ",".join(v)) for k,v in result.items()]
print(result)
```

---

Or using `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
result = {}
for k, v in x:
    result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

---

**Output:**

```
['8: K,N', '1: A,B', '2: A', '3: T,Z', '6: K']
```

Comment: Or if you really need to have nested quotation marks as indicated in the question, just changed the "result line" to `result = ["{}: {}".format(k, ', '.join('"{0}"'.format(w) for w in v)) for k, v in b.items()]`

Comment: I did not understand anything here. But it works perfectly. Thanks. I will look more into defaultdict.

Comment: @Rakesh, If there are more than 2 value can we do it like - for k,v,i,j in x: result[k].append(j) ?????

Comment: You can use `for i in x:
    result[i[0]].extend(i[1:])`

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your strings once you group your elements as you described, and for that you can use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [[1,'A'],[1,'B'],[2,'A'],[3,'T'],[3,'Z'],[8,'K'],[6,'K'],[8,'N']]

{k: [v[1] for v in g] for k, g in groupby(sorted(a), key=lambda x: x[0])}
#{1: ['A', 'B'], 2: ['A'], 3: ['T', 'Z'], 6: ['K'], 8: ['K', 'N']}
```

From this, as of Python 3.6, you can do the following:

```
r = {k: [v[1] for v in g] for k, g in groupby(sorted(a), key=lambda x: x[0])}
result = ["{0}: {','.join(repr(i) for i in {1})}".format(k, v) for k, v in r.items()]

result
#["1: 'A','B'", "2: 'A'", "3: 'T','Z'", "6: 'K'", "8: 'K','N'"]
```

Comment: The output is a list of strings, and not a dictionary, also groupby is prehaps overkill here